# Pokemon Go Gym Glitch?

Tags: pokemon-go

In Pokemon Go when I try to fight a gym it starts the first battle and then exits from the battle, back to the gym screen.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

This could be happening because you get too far away from the gym.

This will do this if you leave the gym area, unlike catching pokemon, where once you engaged with a wild pokemon, you can go away and the engagement continues, you must be close to the gym at all times to battle or train in it.